# Can a circle be divided into congruent shapes with one not sharing a point with circumferences?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Just wondering out of curiosity. For instance, this does not qualify:

[image]

Having been trying for a while, I would appreciate if someone can give a proof that it is impossible (in case it is). Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Are you asking whether a circle can be partitioned into several pieces, all of them congruent, where exactly one of the pieces does not touch the circumference of the circle?

Comment: Added a compact ppt-drawn image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean *at least* one rather than *exactly* one, then the second tiling below qualifies:

[image]

This is from Haddley and Worsley, "[Infinite families of monohedral disk tilings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03794)" (2015), which I found via the similar MathOverflow question "[Is it possible to dissect a disk into congruent pieces, so that a neighborhood of the origin is contained within a single piece?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17313)". That question seems to still be an open problem.

Comment: What an interesting paper! I particularly like this one [circ_tess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcDhd.jpg)